# How to reference an open Excel sheet that I don't know the name of?

Tags: vba, excel

Background:
I'm recording a macro in Excel that transfers data between three different workbooks that are all open at the same time (I'm recording it and then going into the code and fixing any bugs because I have zero experience with coding).

Problem:
Two of the workbooks will always be used while the third changes (ex. RFQ_1234, RFQ_1235). The macro works great, except each time I use it, I have to debug it and re-enter the name of the third workbook. How do I change my code so that it references the 3rd workbook without using a specific name?

Disclaimer:
I know .select is super slow, I don't care. It just needs to work. Also, I know very little about coding, so please explain even the smallest details.

Example of code:

```
Windows("RFQ_14446.xlsm").Activate
Range("J51").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("RFQ_14446.xlsm").Activate
Range("D27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("RFQ_14446.xlsm").Activate
Range("D5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Will the 3rd workbook always be the only one whose name begins with "RFQ_" ?

Comment: Yes it will always begin with "RFQ_" and then numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing as little of your code as possible (as requested!)...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim wbName As String

    wbName = GetRfqWbName("RFQ_")
    If Len(wbName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Didn't find the RFQ workbook!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Windows(wbName).Activate
    Range("J51").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows(wbName).Activate
    Range("D27").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows(wbName).Activate
    Range("D5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

'get the name of the first workbook which begins with sName...
Function GetRfqWbName(sName As String) As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like sName & "*" Then GetRfqWbName = wb.Name
        Exit For
    Next wb
End Function
```

EDIT: here's an improved version of the `Tester` sub above

```
Sub Tester2()

    Dim wbName As String, shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet

    wbName = GetRfqWbName("RFQ_")
    If Len(wbName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Didn't find the RFQ workbook!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'for example: you can substitute the sheet names instead
        Set shtSrc = Workbooks(wbName).Sheets(1)
        Set shtDest = Workbooks("Transfer Template.xlsm").Sheets(1)
    End If

    shtSrc.Range("J51").Copy shtDest.Range("B1")
    shtSrc.Range("D27").Copy shtDest.Range("B2")
    shtSrc.Range("D5").Copy shtDest.Range("B3")

End Sub
```

Comment: To add some of the requested explanation: @Tim has written a function which cycles through all open Workbooks, and returns the name of the first Workbook beginning with "RFQ_". This name is then stored in a variable `wbName`, and is used to reference the Workbook from there on.

Comment: Tim, just realized that this code won't work if I have anything else open besides "Transfer Template" and the "RFQ_" workbook. I currently have those workbooks open as well as a workbook entitled "Protected_JD_Form", and it's not working.

Comment: @Tim Williams It gives me the "Didn't find the RFQ workbook!" message box.

Comment: @TimWilliams it's still telling me that it didn't find the RFQ workbook.

Comment: Then there's no workbook open with a name that begins with that string, or it's open in a different instance of Excel (any files open in other instances will not be part of the Workbooks collection for the instance running the macro)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it by index or `activesheet`.

```
Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet

ws = Workbook.ActiveSheet

ws.Cell(A1).Value = "SomeValue"
```

Or you can use the index.

```
Set ws = ExcelApplication.Worksheets(1)
```

Comment: So do I then replace all the Windows("RFQ_14446.xlsm") with Workbook.ActiveSheet?

Comment: I'm not sure what the Windows("RFQ.xlsm") is doing. Never used it like that before.

Comment: I thought that was the part that was referencing the 3rd workbook.