# Excel macro only works when certain workbook is opened first

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro for Excel that transfers data between three workbooks. Two of the workbooks stay the same and are merely templates. The third workbook is an output from a business management system. It changes, but will always start with "RFQ_". For instance; RFQ_14787, RFQ_14839, RFQ_63528.

The code below was written to cycle through the open workbooks, select the one that starts with "RFQ_", and store that name in a variable to be used throughout the code.

In testing this code I have discovered that it only works if the workbook entitled "RFQ_XXXXX" is opened first.

All credit for the code goes to @Tim Williams and his answer to one of my other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189892/how-to-reference-an-open-excel-sheet-that-i-dont-know-the-name-of).

```
Sub Tester2()

Dim wbName As String, shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet

wbName = GetRfqWbName("RFQ_")
If Len(wbName) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Didn't find the RFQ workbook!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    'for example: you can substitute the sheet names instead
    Set shtSrc = Workbooks(wbName).Sheets(1)
    Set shtDest = Workbooks("Transfer Template.xlsm").Sheets(1)
End If

shtSrc.Range("J51").Copy shtDest.Range("B1")

End Sub
'get the name of the first workbook which begins with sName...
Function GetRfqWbName(sName As String) As String

Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like sName & "*" Then GetRfqWbName = wb.Name
    Exit For
Next wb
End Function
```

I'm only looking for an explanation, out of curiosity, but if anyone has a way to run the macro without opening the "RFQ_" workbook first I would appreciate it.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that "For Each wb In Workbooks" looks through *open workbooks only* to see which one of them has Rfq in the name. If the RFQ_ workbook will always be in the same place, you can specifically target the destination, open the file, and then run the code as you have it here.

Comment: If you do not know the name of the workbook then i would recommend looping though all the open workbooks and letting the user choose the workbook where the macro has to be run

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: All three workbooks are open, including the workbook with "RFQ" in the name.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I appreciate the suggestion, and that is a good idea. However, I would like to keep this process as automated as possible.

Comment: i actually do not understand your question then... can you rephrase it for me?

Comment: You need to debug what's going on in the `GetRfqWbName` function.  Add a `Debug.Print wb.Name` inside the For loop and look at the output in the Immediate pane of the VB editor.  Do you see what you expect?

Comment: @SiddharthRout My apologies, please see my edit. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: I see @TimWilliams is here now. Since he has already been handling your previous question, i will leave you in his capable hands :)

Comment: @TimWilliams I do not. It is giving me the name of one of my other workbooks that is open, "Protected_JD_Form.xlsx".

Comment: Then as I think I noted in your original question, it's possible that the workbook you're looking for is open in a different instance of Excel. Close it, and open it from the same instance where you have your "Transfer Template" workbook opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunally I am not allowed to comment so I have to make this an answer but as fas as I see the problem is in:

```
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like sName & "*" Then GetRfqWbName = wb.Name
    Exit For
Next wb
```

The `Exit For` is not part of the `if`-clause so it will break the loop everytime after the first Workbook has been checked - whether successfully or not...

**Edit**: Change the code as follows to solve the problem

```
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like sName & "*" Then 
       GetRfqWbName = wb.Name
       Exit For
    End If
Next wb
```

Comment: @Wooz - good eye.  That was not how I originally wrote that function.